# Does Loopback able to support all TCP/IP protocols

Tags: windows, networking, ip-address, arp

Does a Windows loopback adapter supports ACD and duplicate IPs. Say we have a code that supports full TCP stack and we bridge the program to loopback using PCAP.

If in case I set both the address same - is it the right way to test ACD? Do we need always wired devices to test ACD?

Comment: What is ACD? It's not a protocol or technology I'm familiar with.

Comment: Address Conflict Detection